# Whenever adding information to a csv folder through , it will go down to a random row

Tags: python, csv, tkinter, tkinter-entry

So I am making a GUI that can both find and add a user through their customer ID with python and tkinter  and the csv file is formatted as:

> ID: Name: Address: State: Email:
>
> 10004 John, 123 fake st QLD johnsmith@yahoo.com

basically like that
My problem is that whenever I add a user it will always go into a random row in the bottom somewhere and the ID is wrong because I need the ID to add one to the last ID. Basically, if the last row had the ID 10004 the program would add one to the ID and assign that customer to the ID 10005
Here's what I have:

```
def addUser():
    with open("C:/Users/Shay/Documents/Notebooks/ITN/Assessment/ITN Term 4 Assessment Student Data.csv", 'r') as csvTwo:
        fileCSVTwo = csv.reader(csvTwo)
        num = 0
        for row in fileCSVTwo:
            if row[0] != " ":
                row = row[0]
            else:
                row = 0
        row = int(row)
        ro2 = row + 1
        ro3 = str(ro2)

with open("C:/Users/Shay/Documents/Notebooks/ITN/Assessment/ITN Term 4 Assessment Student Data.csv",'a', newline='\n')as csvThree:
    fields = ("%s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s" % (ro3, l1.get(), l2.get(), l3.get(), l4.get(), l5.get(), l6.get(), l7.get())).split(",")
    writer = csv.writer(csvThree)
    writer.writerow(fields)

l1.delete(0, END)
l2.delete(0, END)
l3.delete(0, END)
l4.delete(0, END)
l5.delete(0, END)
l6.delete(0, END)
l7.delete(0, END)

root = Tk()

Label(root, text="Add user:").grid(row=14,column=1,)
Label(root, text="First Name:").grid(row=16,)
Label(root, text="Last Name:").grid(row=17)
Label(root, text="Address:").grid(row=18)
Label(root, text="City:").grid(row=19)
Label(root, text="State:").grid(row=20)
Label(root, text="Postal:").grid(row=21)
Label(root, text="Email:").grid(row=22)

l1 = Entry(root)
l2 = Entry(root)
l3 = Entry(root)
l4 = Entry(root)
l5 = Entry(root)
l6 = Entry(root)
l7 = Entry(root)

l1.grid(row=16, column=1)
l2.grid(row=17, column=1)
l3.grid(row=18, column=1)
l4.grid(row=19, column=1)
l5.grid(row=20, column=1)
l6.grid(row=21, column=1)
l7.grid(row=22, column=1)


Button(root, text='Add', command=addUser).grid(row=28, column=1)

# Basically the canvas of the GUI
# Where this part is where we paint
# And the code above is the picture we are trying to make

my_gui = startPage(root)
root.mainloop()
```

Also just to mention I am a novice coder and don't have much skill
Also I am running python 3 and running the IDE Pycharm

Comment: Perhaps you could do `ro3 = max(int(row[0]) for row in fileCSVTwo if row[0] != " ")+1`. Now not id of the last entry returned by your CSV reader is incremented by one but the maximum is incremented by one and that ensures that it is not used by any other row.

Comment: Please reduce this down to a [mcve]. There seems to be a lot of unrelated code there. For example, do you really need 7 labels and 7 entry widgets to duplicate the problem? Can you duplicate it with 2?

Comment: The csv file has 7 columns excluding the ID and the user needs to input their information into the GUI

Comment: also I tried  ro3 = max(int(row[0]) for row in fileCSVTwo if row[0] != " ")+1 , and I think I am implementing it into the code wrong